# Drawing text with canvas

Tags: android, canvas

How do I clear the text rendered on canvas? I wanted to clear the text written on canvas by method `canvas.drawText()`. The text should be updated every time, as if I were setting a digital clock showing time.

Comment: that hook right under the down vote button of the answer of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

try to redraw with a new paint like:

```
Paint paint = new Paint();    
paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.CLEAR));
```

more about porterDuff modes: https://softwyer.wordpress.com/2012/01/21/1009/

Comment: The draw colour would colour the whole canvas

Comment: yep, my bad. redraw your text with the paint mentioned above

Comment: you can't *update* your text, you have to clear it by redrawing it in Mode.Clear and then draw the new text in a different Mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you are within the onDraw of a view, the canvas you get is cleared every time the method is called.

If you have a surfaceview or a bitmap backed canvas, just redraw your background. For eg, if your background is white, then `fontCanvas.drawARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);`

Essentially, get away from thinking that your canvas is a piece of paper. The closer you get to the hardware, the less like a paper it gets. If you get out of that thinking, the answers to questions like these will be obvious.